# SQL query to stop duplicate ID insert in a table using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to stop duplicate MessageId inserted into the TestMobileRecipient table. At the moment all section of the sql query work fine except "Insert Mobile detail into the Email Recipient table" section at the moment when the store procedure is run more than once I have duplicate messageid in TestMobileRecipient table. Any suggestion how to resolve this issue

```
 Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[ImportMessage]
 AS
 BEGIN
 --- Insert Message details in the Email table
  INSERT INTO TestTextMessage (MessageId, Origin, MessageBody, 
       MessageSent, DateCreated, DateSent,DontSendBefore) 
  SELECT Id, Origin, MessageBody,MessageSent,DateCreated,DateSent ,DontSendBefore
  FROM TextMessage
  WHERE 
      DontSendBefore <= GETDate()  and  DateSent is null and MessageSent = 0

--- Only run update when the query above return a value
    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 

--- Update TextMessage Table after the data is insert in the Email table
 UPDATE TextMessage 
     SET DateSent= GETDate(),
     DontSendBefore = null,
     MessageSent = 1
  WHERE
    Id= (select MessageId 
  FROM 
    TestTextMessage
  WHERE 
     TextMessage.id= TestTextMessage.MessageId)

 -- Insert Mobile detail into the Email Recipient table

   INSERT Into TestMobileRecipient(MessageId, MobileNumber)
   SELECT
      MessageId, MobileNumber
   FROM 
      MobileRecipient
   WHERE
      MessageId =(SELECT   MessageId 
   FROM   
       TestTextMessage
   WHERE
      MobileRecipient.MessageId= TestTextMessage.MessageId)
END
```

Comment: If there are multiple rows, with a different value for `MobileNumber` what would you be expected to be input? Can that happen?

Comment: @Lamu for example if I run the query for the first time I will have 10 rows in the TestMobileRecipient table. I don't want if I run it  to have the 10 previous row inserted again in the table

Comment: I'm on my phone now, so can't give an example, however , look up `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `WHERE` clause like following, that verifies if the `MessageId` already exists in the `TestMobileRecipient` table:

```
INSERT INTO TestMobileRecipient
    (
        MessageId
    )
            SELECT
                MessageId,
                MobileNumber
            FROM
                MobileRecipient
            WHERE
                MessageId =
                (
                    SELECT
                        MessageId
                    FROM
                        TestTextMessage
                    WHERE
                        MobileRecipient.MessageId = TestTextMessage.MessageId
                )
                AND NOT EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT
                        MessageId
                    FROM
                        TestMobileRecipient tmr2
                    WHERE
                       tmr2.MessageId = MobileRecipient.MessageId
                );
```

Or if you would like to get a warning while inserting a duplicate value, you can create an index like following:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IndexTestMobileRecipient] ON TestMobileRecipient 
(
    MessageId

)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, 
DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: your answer partially worked the duplicate stopped. But when I insert a new message in the MobileRecipient table  with  a new  messageid not previously in that table, that messageId doesn't insert in the TestMobileRecipient table. any suggestion please. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks I solve the issue. need to be tmr2.MessageId = MobileRecipient.MessageId. I will update and accept the answer. Thanks Samita

Comment: Glad it worked.. @EricAimeTchatchoua and thanks for accepting my answer!